# Conditionally define a function inside another function in Julia

Tags: julia

Slow to learning newer julia syntax and scoping.

In Julia v1.1.1

what is the explanation for why the MWE below throws error "ff not defined" ?

```
N = 5;
typp = "b";
mu = 2;

function bigfun()

  function f(u,mu)
    ee = mu*u;
    return ee
  end

  function g(uv,mu)
    ee = (mu^2)*uv
    return ee;
  end

  while 1 == 1

    u = ones(N);
    if typp == "a"
      ff(u) = f(u,mu);
    elseif typp == "b"
      ff(u) = g(u,mu);
    end
    fu = ff(u);
    break;

  end

end

bigfun();
```

Comment: You are using global variables (`N`, `typp`, `mu`), which is bad for performance, and a bad idea in general. You should avoid that.  (A style tip: use `while true` instead of `while 1 == 1`.)

Comment: Ok thanks.  Honest (and naive) question, but what if the variables are conceptually global?

Comment: It's the very first tip detailed in https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/.  Use `const` if you really want a global variable.

Comment: thanks for the reminder !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mention in the [Julia Docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/#man-scope-table),

> Julia uses lexical scoping, meaning that a function's scope does not inherit from its caller's scope, but from the scope in which the function was defined.

It is worth reading some examples in the above link but the gist is that the function is defined in the local scope/context of the if/else statement and does not exist outside of that scope (at the end of that function).

Comment: Note that I don't personally think the docs linked above are super clear, so feel free to open an issue here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues if there's parts that can be improved.

Comment: What is best practice to perform the spirit of the above code? In other words, define a function conditionally based on this or that?

Comment: Good question, I just dug around a little and didn't come up with the answer, let me get more eyes on this.

Answer (score 14):

This is a known bug in Julia: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/15602. You can't define an inner function conditionally. There a few ways around this issue:

1. Define `ff` as an anonymous function:

   ```
       if typp == "a"
         ff = u -> f(u,mu)
       elseif typp == "b"
         ff = u -> g(u,mu)
       end
       fu = ff(u)
   ```
2. Define `ff` once, and add the conditional inside of it:

   ```
       function ff(u, typp)
         if typp == "a"
           f(u,mu)
         elseif typp == "b"
           g(u,mu)
         end
       end
       fu = ff(u, typp)
   ```
3. Don't define the function `ff` at all. You don't need to, in the example you provided, just assign `fu` conditionally

   ```
       if typp == "a"
         fu = f(u,mu)
       elseif typp == "b"
         fu = g(u,mu)
       end
   ```

Comment: In my case the fu variable is just a check of sanity, the function is what is actually used in the solver so it's needed.  Thanks for updating with more examples!!

Comment: Can you explain why the anonymous solution actually works?  Ultimately ff is still getting defined inside the if-statement so it's not clear conceptually why it avoids the scoping issue.

Comment: I think the anonymous function trick works because they're two different functions.  It isn't a scoping issue.  For more details, see [this comment](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/15602#issuecomment-226518246) in the already linked issue

Comment: Unfortunately I can't say that cleared it up any, but thanks anyway!