# Wrong results defining a function inside a if-statement in a function scope in Julia

Tags: function, if-statement, scope, julia, compiler-warnings

I find it somewhat strange that it works fine globally, but within a function scope, the compiler resorts to defining a function inside the `ifelse` statement, which I explicitly set to false.

Nonetheless, are there any standards to prevent such confusion, and what isthe underlying compilation logic behind this phenomenon?

I am not sure, but I suppose this issue may be related to [Conditionally define a function inside another function in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65660234/conditionally-define-a-function-inside-another-function-in-julia).

I ran this simple experiment. Initially, I defined the experiment globally, and everything worked as expected. However, when I ran the same code snippet within a function scope, it appears that the output is affected by the `ifelse` statement, despite it being set to false.

```
# weird.jl
function experiment()
    g(x) = 0
    if ( true )
        println("Here")
        g(x) = 0
    elseif (false)
        g(x) = 1
    end
    println("We expect g(1) == 0, and we get g(1) ==", g(1))
end

g(x) = 0
if (true)
    println("Here")
    g(x) = 0
elseif (false)
    g(x) = 1
end
println("We expect g(1) == 0, and we get g(1) ==", g(1))


println("\nExperiment")
experiment()
```

With output

```
WARNING: Method definition g(Any) in module Main at /root/code/weird.jl:3 overwritten at /root/code/weird.jl:6.
WARNING: Method definition g(Any) in module Main at /root/code/weird.jl:6 overwritten at /root/code/weird.jl:8.
Here
We expect g(1) == 0, and we get g(1) ==0

Experiment
Here
We expect g(1) == 0, and we get g(1) ==1
```

Regarding the application. For me the overall goal is to be able to define functions like this

```
function lots_of_computations(mode)
    # Defining variables and computations ....
    if ( mode==Physical )
        g_0(x, t) = 0
        g_1(x) = 0
        g_2(x,t) = 0
    elseif (mode==General)
        g_0(x, t) = 2*ε*sin(2π*t/(100*τ))*sin(2π*x[1]/L)*cos(2π*x[2]/L)
        g_1(x) =  ε*x[1]
        g_2(x,t) =  ε*t*x[2]
    else
        println("not supported")
    end

    # More computations ....
end
```

But, seems like this won't work reliably in a function scope.

Answer (score 3):

As it is explained in https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/15602 (which is linked in [Conditionally define a function inside another function in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65660234/conditionally-define-a-function-inside-another-function-in-julia) that you saw) the currently recommended and safe way to achieve what you want is to use anonymous functions, so your code can look e.g. like:

```
function lots_of_computations(mode)
    # Defining variables and computations ....
    if mode isa Physical
        g_0 = (x, t) -> 0
        g_1 = x -> 0
        g_2 = (x,t) -> 0
    elseif mode isa General
        g_0 = (x, t) -> 2*ε*sin(2π*t/(100*τ))*sin(2π*x[1]/L)*cos(2π*x[2]/L)
        g_1 = x ->  ε*x[1]
        g_2 = (x,t) ->  ε*t*x[2]
    else
        println("not supported")
    end

    # More computations ....
end
```

Note that I changed `mode==Physical` to `mode isa Physical` so that the condition is on type of `mode` not on its value. The reason is that in this case the `if` statement will be optimized-out during compilation. The `mode==Physical` condition often also could be optimized out (thanks to constant propagation in the compiler), but it is not guaranteed that it would be always the case, so it is usually better to make such a condition based on type not on value of the argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have been stumbling on this issue several times :)